# Classic ASP Type Mismatch with If Then Statement

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Can someone please tell me why this is tossing a Type Mismatch using Classic ASP error?

```vb
If (strPaidByPO = True) OR (arrResult(0) = "1") Then
  'Do Stuff
Else
  'Do Other stuff
End if
```

arrResults is an Array and strPaidByPO is a variable.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Before the `If` statement type the following (I think you may be making assumptions about the Types).

```vb
Call Response.Write(TypeName(strPaidByPO) & "<br />")
Call Response.Write(TypeName(arrResult) & "<br />")
Call Response.Flush()
```

If your variables are of the type you expected you should get the following output

```
Boolean
Variant()
```

Also you might receive this if your Array is multidimensional in which case you need to specify all the dimensions.

The other possibility is `arrResult(0)` contains something other than a `String`. In which case use `TypeName(arrResult(0))` to check what that is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see result based on which you can correct your script:

```
 response.write(cStr(strPaidByPO) & "- My strPaidByPO value<br>")
 response.write(arrResult(0) & "- My Array value")


 If (strPaidByPO = True) OR (cStr(arrResult(0)) = "1") Then
   'Do Stuff
 Else
   'Do Other stuff
 End if
```

but if your strPaidByPO contain values other then true - false (Boolean) you need to review your approach to this completely. For example if strPaidByPO  is NULL or empty your script will trough you an error like you described.